# Trying to Create a Generate_Series Function in Oracle db

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create
or replace Function Generate_Series (
  MinNumber INTEGER,
  MaxNumber INTEGER,
  NumberToSkip INTEGER
) Return Numbers_t 
As 
  newNumber INTEGER: = MinNumber;
  Numbers_t Numbers_x: = Numbers_t();
Begin 
  for x in (
  with s as (
    Select
      rNo
    From
      (
        select
          level rno
        from
          dual connect by level <= enNumber
      ) A
    Where
      A.rNo >= stNumber
  )
  select
    rno
  from
    s
) loop 
if x.rno <> MinNumber then 
  newNumber: = newNumber + NumberToSkip;
end if;
if newNumber >= MaxNumber then 
  Return;
end if;
  Numbers_x.EXTEND; 
  Numbers_x(Numbers_x.COUNT): = newNumber;
  end loop;
  Return Numbers_x;
End;
```

Seeing this error

```
"Function GENERATE_SERIES compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
0/0       PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
13/8      PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
Errors: check compiler log"
```

Can someone help me with this TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. You don't need a SELECT or FROM DUAL or anything similar. 
A plain FOR loop is enough.

Assuming numbers_t is defined as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE numbers_t AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

Then you can use this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION generate_series (minnumber INTEGER, maxnumber INTEGER)
   RETURN numbers_t
   PIPELINED
   DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
   FOR i IN minnumber .. maxnumber LOOP
      PIPE ROW (i);
   END LOOP;
   RETURN;
END;
/
```

To use the function, you need:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE(generate_series(1,42))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not to piddle on your party, but:

1. Calling user-defined functions from SQL in Oracle is generally a Bad Thing, causing no end of problems.
2. If you need to generate a series of numbers in Oracle the usual way to do it is with a simple `SELECT...FROM DUAL` query, as follows:

   `SELECT LEVEL-1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL-1 < 24`

This generates a list of number from 0 to 23 - adjust as needed.

Comment: I slightly disagree. While PL/SQL performance indeed leaves much to be desired from such an expensive product, especially the (undocumented and unsupported)`connect by level` "trick" has more than once given me major headaches in query performance.

Comment: I would not refer to using `CONNECT BY LEVEL` in this manner as an "undocumented and unsupported trick". CONNECT BY LEVEL is certainly a supported feature of the database, and using it to generate a sequence of numbers is IMO just using a feature of the database in a reasonable manner. I will agree that overuse of this or any other feature can be problematic, depending on how it's applied.

Comment: This was undocumented in earlier versions. E.g. the 11g manual states that "*one expression in condition must be qualified with the PRIOR operator*" (must being the operative word here). And Laurent Schneider once [stated this as well](https://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2005/11/connect-by-to-generate-rows.html) But this does not seem to be the case in the current manuals. So apparently Oracle changed this

Comment: I stand corrected. (OK, technically I *sit* corrected :-).

Comment: In my humble opinion, it's the most straightforward solution. Why involving PLSQL when it's not absolutely necessary?